# Two nginx instances for domain and subdomain?

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx config for `nextcloud.mydomain.com` which serves nextcloud from `/srv/www/nextcloud` via php-handle `server unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock`.

It has its own nginx config at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nextcloud`, with its own `server` config for both 80 and 443.

Then I have a second nginx config for `mydomain.com` which serves wordpress from `/srv/www/wordpress` located at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/wordpress`, again both `server` for 80 and 443.

Both instances seem to be working fine.

Is there an issue having this configuration? Should I have it in just one config? Can they somehow conflict?

Comment: This sounds perfectly normal. Why are you concerned?

Comment: Because I get sometimes 504 timeouts. But I am actually thinking it's my provider, SSH is also sometimes excruciatingly slow. But I want to exclude errors on my side

Comment: I was just updating nextcloud and from the updater I would get 504 (it's probably polling or having some connection open to check on progress). Very generally the sites feel sluggish and slow, with various degrees of response times.

Comment: Nextcloud is slow and pretty bloated. Use the command line updater.